Defining the real projective line via equivalence relation
I'd just like to know if my approach is correct. Let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $\mathbb R^2$ defined as:
$$(x_1,y_1)\sim(x_2,y_2) \iff \exists\lambda\in\mathbb R\smallsetminus\{0\} : x_1 = \lambda x_2 \land y_1 = \lambda y_2$$
Now define:
$$\widehat{\mathbb R} := (\mathbb R^2\smallsetminus\{(0,0)\})/{\sim}$$
And by definition:
$$\infty \sim (a,0)$$
For any $a\in\mathbb R$.
Is this a correct way to define the real projective line?

It is common, when learning about the projective line, to think it as the real line together with $\infty$. However, the truth is that in the projective line there is no "point at infinity". There is no special point in the projective line, it is completely homogeneus. IF you want to identify the real line as a subset of the projective line, then you can choose ANY point as $\infty$, and when you remove it you'll get a copy of the real numbers. A common choice is to take the (equivalence class of the) point $(a,0)$, but is important to emphasize that this is just a matter of taste and convenience, but that point is not different from the others.
That said, your definitions are almost correct. It should be "for any $a\in \Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$”.

That is correct, but I would more precisely write that $\infty$ is the class of any element of the form $(a,0)$. (What you wrote suggests that $\infty$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$, not $\hat{\mathbb{R}}$.)
